# How do I use a ValueConverter with Databinding in Winforms

Tags: winforms, data-binding

In WPF it is easy to use a ValueConverter to format values etc,  (in our case convert some numbers into a different unit,  e.g km to miles)

I know it can be done in Winforms, but all my Googleing just brings up results for WPF and Silverlight.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/q/3430217/240733

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You can [use a `TypeConverter`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32006523/240733) if you're able and willing to decorate the data source property with a custom attribute.

Otherwise you have to attach to the [`Parse`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.binding.parse(v=VS.100).aspx) and [`Format`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.binding.format(v=VS.100).aspx) events of a [`Binding`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.binding.aspx) object. This, unfortunately, eliminates using the designer for your binding for all but the simplest scenarios.

For example, let's say you wanted a `TextBox` bound to an integer column representing kilometers and you wanted the visual representation in miles:

In the constructor:

```
Binding bind = new Binding("Text", source, "PropertyName");

bind.Format += bind_Format;
bind.Parse += bind_Parse;

textBox.DataBindings.Add(bind);
```

...

```
void bind_Format(object sender, ConvertEventArgs e)
{
    int km = (int)e.Value;

    e.Value = ConvertKMToMiles(km).ToString();
}

void bind_Parse(object sender, ConvertEventArgs e)
{
    int miles = int.Parse((string)e.Value);

    e.Value = ConvertMilesToKM(miles);
}
```

Comment: It's worth mentioning that this technique will only cover scenarios where Binding objects are used and exposed. It won't work with grids and other complex binding controls, unless of course they have their own Format / Parse API. Therefore, there really isn't any "generic" way of using value converters within WinForms databinding mechanisms, unfortunately.

Answer (score 5):

Another option is to have a specific ViewModel for the form which exposes data in the format you need to display on the form. You can easily achieve it by using [AutoMapper](http://automapper.codeplex.com/) and building your own [Formatter](http://popcyclical.com/PermaLink,guid,2279094b-3c1a-45d8-9b7a-f7e47103612a.aspx).

This way you will have full support for designer too.