# How can return a text based on value in database in EF6 using get method

Tags: c#, entity-framework, gridview, model, presentation-layer

I create a model using EF6 .My model is like this :

```
public partial class Good
{
    public Good()
    {
        this.InnoviceDetails = new HashSet<InvoiceDetail>();
    }

    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Serial { get; set; }
    public string HasTax { get; set; }
    public string InitialAmount { get; set; }
    public string Group { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<InvoiceDetail> InnoviceDetails { get; set; }
}
```

One of the my columns is **HasTax** and the value of this is **1** and **0** ,but in **mygridview** i need to change these values (0,1). i mean if the value is `1` shows **Yes** and if it is `0` shows **No**.I want to do these using `get` method of my model ?Is it possible ?

Get method checks the values in database and return proper values to `gridview` or Presentation layer ?

Best regards

Comment: What UI do you use? Windows Forms, WPF, or is it an ASP.NET page?

Comment: Similar questions have been already asked - try to read: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15267666/entity-framework-code-first-convert-between-class-boolean-and-column-integer; http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19370104/convert-value-when-mapping; http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6708996/convert-from-to-string-in-database-to-boolean-property-entity-framework-4-1/6709186#6709186

Comment: And what do you mean by 'using get method of my model'?

Comment: I mean i checked the value in get method ,because the get method returns value of an object

Comment: You mean getter method in property(Int32 Value{get;}) or some loading method that loads your entities?

Comment: some loading method that loads my entities

Comment: I have given you those links - have you tried them? There are not many ways to do what you want in UI-agnostic way. And I doubt that someone can produce anything different from what is already proposed.

Comment: yes but it just for avoiding database mapping

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you:

1) Don't want to directly change your model or create views.
2) Or add any additional properties that will be used only for binding-with-conversion.

Then you are left with two main variants I could think of:

1) Create a semi-wrapper that exposes your original model and additional special property for binding-with-conversion:

```
public class ModelSemiWrapperBase<TModel> 
{
   public ModelSemiWrapperBase(TModel model)
   {
       this.Model = model;
   }
   public TModel Model
   {
       get;
       private set;
   }
}

public class GoodSemiWrapper : ModelSemiWrapperBase<Good>
{
    public String HasTax
    {
        get
        {
            return (this.Model.HasTax == 0) ? ("Yes") : ("No");
        }
        set {...}
    }
}
```

Just do not forget about INotifyPropertyChanged and changes notification. Also in this case you will have to manually add columns in the DataGridView.

2) Handle events in the DataGridView:

Something like [How do I use a ValueConverter with Databinding in Winforms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2652875/how-do-i-use-a-valueconverter-in-with-databinding-in-winforms), just with dataGridView using the [CellValueChanged](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.cellvaluechanged(v=vs.110).aspx), [CellValidating](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.cellvalidating(v=vs.110).aspx), [DataBindingComplete](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.databindingcomplete(v=vs.110).aspx) or other similar [events](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview_events(v=vs.110).aspx).
I am not even sure which events you should really use. And I'd not gone using such a way. It is too error-prone and it strongly bundles your dataGridView with validation and conversion logic.